# compiled apk is trying to reach metor server react native

Tags: android, react-native, metro-bundler

I don't know really why my compiled apk is trying to reach metor server

I am creating a iOS / android app using react-native

The build was working before

```sh
cd android/
./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace
```

Generated in `android/app/build/outputs/apk/release`

[image]

Comment: It is a little bit unclear where you expect your app to connect to the Meteor server. At least there is no code in your question. Could you add the code, please?

Comment: `react-native` is using meteor only in development, on IOS or android it should be compiled and not use meteor server. but in my case not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error showing your metro bundle is not found. You need to create bundle using following command

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

Other way to create release build

1. Place the `my-release-key.keystore` file under the android/app directory in your project folder
2. Edit the file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties
    and add the following (replace ***** with the correct keystore password, alias and key password

> MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore
>   MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
>   MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=***** MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****

3. Edit the file android/app/build.gradle in your project folder and add the signing config

   android { 
           defaultConfig { ... } 
               signingConfigs { 
                  release { 
                         storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE) 
                         storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                         keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                         keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD } } 
   buildTypes { 
       release { ... 
       signingConfig signingConfigs.release } } } ...
4. Run this command on terminal

   react-native run-android --variant=release

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android